# Extracting Multiple Value from SOAP Response

Tags: soapui

I have an XML Response in SOAP which has the below format

```
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
    <Status diffgr:id="Status12" msdata:rowOrder="11">
    <id>28</id>
    <name>Review</name>
    <categoryId>3</categoryId>
    <assignrule>P</assignrule>
    <ismoveAssign>0</ismoveAssign>
    <isActive>1</isActive>
    </Status>
    </NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

The following XPath shown below if I execute the same in XPath Match configuration of SOAPUI please find the screen shot attached

```
//*[local-name() = 'NewDataSet']/*[local-name()='Status'][12]/*[local-name()='name']
```

But I have many such values which need to extracted by writing an XQuery.

[image]

```
<Result>
{
    for $x in //*[local-name() = 'NewDataSet']/*[local-name()='Status']/*    [local-name()='name']

    return <name> string ($x) </name>
}
</Result>
```

The above result gives Invalid XPath.

Can someone help me where I am going wrong? Would this information be sufficient?

Comment: It is impossible with the available information. Would you please provide the the response and mentioned data are you interested in. Edit the question and update the information.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you're using an `XPath Match` assertion with a `XQuery` expression. If you check the SOAPUI execution log you will see:

```
22:19:20,008 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: XPath syntax error at char 0 in {<}
: Node constructor expressions are allowed only in XQuery, not in XPath].
```

There is a specific assertion of `XQuery Math`, use this instead:

[image]

Hope it helps,